# Ellipse stretch has no effect

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, ellipse, stretch

Can anybody explain why `Stretch` has no effect in `Ellipse` element. No matter do I use `None`,`Fill`,`UniformToFill` or `Uniform` the result is always the same.

If I use this same code inside `DataTemplate` (`GridView`) there it works as it should to works.

```
<Button x:Name="UI_Application_LogIn_ProfilePictureButton_Button" Style="{StaticResource LogInButton}" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumBrush}" IsTabStop="False" UseSystemFocusVisuals="False">
    <Grid x:Name="UI_Application_LogIn_ProfilePicture_Grid" IsHitTestVisible="False">
        <Ellipse x:Name="UI_Application_LogIn_ProfilePicture" Width="160" Height="160">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <ImageBrush x:Name="UI_Application_LogIn_ProfilePictureImageBrush" Stretch="UniformToFill" AlignmentY="Top"/>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
        <Ellipse x:Name="UI_Application_LogIn_ProfilePictureNonStaticLightEffect" Width="160" Height="160" Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentRevealBorderBrush}"/>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

Comment: I found the reason why stretch didn't work. It was really brain fart. I forgot to use `Stretch` in my code when I create new `ImageBrush`. So adding line `ShapeImageBrush.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;` after creating new `ImageBrush` fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason why stretch didn't work. It was really brain fart. I forgot to use Stretch in my code when I create new ImageBrush. So adding line `if (BrushStretch != null) (TargetShape.Fill as ImageBrush).Stretch = BrushStretch.Value;` after creating new ImageBrush fix the problem.

```
    //STORAGE FILE TO SHAPE
    public static async Task<Shape> StorageFileToShape(Shape TargetShape, StorageFile SourceStorageFile, Stretch? BrushStretch, AlignmentX? BrushAlignmentX, AlignmentY? BrushAlignmentY)
    {
        //IF SHAPE NULL RETURN NULL
        if (TargetShape == null) return null;
        //IF STORAGEFILE NULL OR NOT AVAILABLE RETURN NULL
        if (SourceStorageFile == null || !SourceStorageFile.IsAvailable) return null;
        //IF BRUSH IS NULL OR ITS TYPE ISN'T 'ImageBrush' CREATE NEW BRUSH
        if (TargetShape.Fill == null || TargetShape.Fill.GetType() != typeof(ImageBrush)) TargetShape.Fill = new ImageBrush();
        //SET STRETCH
        if (BrushStretch != null) (TargetShape.Fill as ImageBrush).Stretch = BrushStretch.Value;
        //SET ALIGNMENT X
        if (BrushAlignmentX != null) (TargetShape.Fill as ImageBrush).AlignmentX = BrushAlignmentX.Value;
        //SET ALIGNMENT Y
        if (BrushAlignmentY != null) (TargetShape.Fill as ImageBrush).AlignmentY = BrushAlignmentY.Value;
        //GET PICTURE 
        (TargetShape.Fill as ImageBrush).ImageSource = await StorageFileToBitmapImage(SourceStorageFile);
        //SET SHAPE FILL
        TargetShape.Fill = TargetShape.Fill as ImageBrush;
        //RETURN SHAPE
        return TargetShape;
    }
    //STORAGE FILE TO BITMAP IMAGE
    public static async Task<BitmapImage> StorageFileToBitmapImage(StorageFile SourceStorageFile)
    {
        BitmapImage TargetBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        TargetBitmapImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
        using (var BitmapImageFileStream = await SourceStorageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            await TargetBitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(BitmapImageFileStream);
        }
        return TargetBitmapImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a rounded image then use the Imagex control from the **windows community toolkit**

you can look up and play with imagex [here](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH4TLCQ)
or you can reference on your app by nuget at **Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls**
as for your current issue, it is caused because the stretch only effects the brush inside the eclipse and not the eclipse it self, in order to make scale adjustments like that you have to wrap your eclipse around a **Viewbox** control and then set its **Stretch** Property the same way you would on a image